# C Caesar Cipher ASCII Alphabet Wrap

Tags: c, encryption, cs50, caesar-cipher

I am quite new to C. I would like to be able to shift a letter of the alphabet 'x' number of times to create a basic cipher.

I'm having trouble with the islower() function. I'm using 'i', however, I'm unable to change it to a character.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

string p;

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //if argument count does not equal 2, exit and return 1
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Less or more than 2 arguments given, exiting...\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else //prompt user for plaintext to encrypt
    {
        p = GetString();
    }

    //take the second part of the array (the int entered by user) and store as k (used as the encryption key)
    //string k = argv[1];
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);

    //function:
    // c = (p + k) % 26;    
    //iterate over the characters in the string
    //p represents the position in the alphabet of a plaintext letter
    //c likewise represents a position in the alphabet
    char new;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(p); i < n; i++)
    if (islower((char)i))
    {
        //printf("%c\n", p[i] + (k % 26));
        printf("This prints p:%s\n", p);
        printf("This prints i:%d\n", (char)i);
        printf("This prints k:%d\n", k);
        printf("This prints output of lower(i):%d\n", islower(i));
        new = (p[i] - 97);
        new += k;
        //printf("%d\n", new  %26 + 97);
        //printf("i = |%c| is lowercase\n", i);
        printf("%c\n", new % 26 + 97);
    }
    else {
        //printf("%c", p[i] + (k % 26));
        printf("This prints p:%s\n", p);       
        printf("This prints i:%d\n", (char)i);
        printf("This prints k:%d\n", k);
        printf("This prints output of lower(i):%d\n", islower(i));
        new = (p[i] - 65);
        new += k;
        //printf("%d\n", new % 26 + 65);
        //printf("i = |%c| is uppercase\n", i);
        printf("%c\n", new % 26 + 65);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Outputs:

```
jharvard@appliance (~/Dropbox/CS50x/pset2): ./caesar2 1
zZ < here is my input
This prints p:zZ
This prints i:0
This prints k:1
This prints output of lower(i):0
G < here is fails, lower case z should move to lower case a
This prints p:zZ
This prints i:1
This prints k:1
This prints output of lower(i):0
A < here is a success! upper case Z moves to upper case A
```

Comment: The modulo operator `%` has a higher precedence than `+`. I would use parentheses in the `printf()` if I were you.

Comment: I'v update it, thanks.

Comment: I think reza means (p[i] + k) % 26 instead.

Comment: @user1895961 I do. :-)

Comment: in your commented code but not in whats executed. there's actually an error in what I said above, should be  p[i] + (k % 26).

Comment: What's the point of adding some non-negative number less than 26 to an alphabet, if it sends the character out of range?
I hardly get it.

Comment: Curious to know if anybody else has ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alphabets in English are used in C as defined in ASCII. 'Z' (ASCII 90) is followed by '{' only (ASCII 91).
To go back to 'A', you should do all the shifts in the following manner:

1. Subtract your ASCII character by 65. It'll lead to output between 0
   to 25 (inclusive).
2. Add the displacement (shift distance).
3. Take a modulo 26, to wrap around your result.
4. Add 65 back again.

Remember, this will work only for capital alphabets of the English language. So you may want to use `toupper()` from the `ctype.h` library.

If you want to add similar functionality for small characters, do the above procedure, replacing 65 by 97.
To check if you got a small character or a capital, use `isupper()`.
You'll have to add more and specific code for special characters.

Comment: isupper() and islower() is definitely what I am looking for.

Comment: For step 1, int new = p - 65 However, the output is a string. Shouldn't I keep it as an int?

Comment: You could do it any way you like. I would recommend a `char` though, coz it takes less memory.

Comment: You could mark the answer as correct if it answers your query.

Comment: new = (p[i] - 65) I'm unable to get an output from 0 to 25.

Comment: Oh, 'z's value is 122, I was looking at capital letters.

Comment: also 'replacing 65 by 90' shouldn't it be 97 instead?

Comment: Err yes! You're right! Didn't keep track of my count!
Corrected the answer.

Comment: I'm making progress! Can you look at the updated code above and tell me why it fails for capital letters?

Comment: I don't see a reason why it would work. You swapped up the places of 65 and 97.
Small letters start from 97, so if a character of plaintext `islower()`, you should do: `new = (p[i] -97 + k) % 26 + 97;` and then simply print `new`. Same will work for Capital Letters with 65 instead of 97.

Comment: I believe my issue is with the 'if (islower(i))' because i represents an int and not a character.

Comment: It should not be a problem, and as much as I can see, the prototype of `islower()` is
`int islower(int)`
If it still doesn't work, you may try type-casting, or making i a `char`, or as a last resort, write your own function.
I would write my own function as its really easy here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, I was unable to get 'i' to work as a character with type-cast or using char. I've updated my code above (added print statements).

Comment: Any ideas for a function to solve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`islower((char)i)` checks whether the loop counter is a lowercase character.

You want to test the character at that position - `islower(p[i])`.